# Should I use `app.exec()` or `app.exec_()` in my PyQt application?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I use Python 3 and PyQt5. Here's my test PyQt5 program, focus on the last 2 lines:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class window(QWidget):
def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setWindowTitle('test')
    self.resize(250,200)

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
w=window()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
#sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know `exec` is a language keyword in Python. But code on [Official PyQt5 Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#object-destruction-on-exit) *(specifically the **Object Destruction on Exit** part)*. I see that example shows use of `app.exec()` which confuses me.

When I tested it on my machine. I found there is no any visible difference from my end. Both with and without `_` produces the same output in no time difference.

My question is:

- Is there anything wrong going when I use `app.exec()`? like clashing with Python's internal `exec`? I suspect because both `exec`'s are executing something.
- If not, can I use both interchangeably?

Comment: In PyQt5, you don't need `sys.exit()` at all. `app.exec_()` or `app.exec()` alone is enough and it works normally. They fixed some things in PyQt5 under the hood so that you don't need that `sys.exit()` anymore. If you want your code to run on PyQt4, then have `sys.exit()` there. Also, `app.exec_()` and `app.exec()` are interchangable, so you can use whichever you like. If you want your code to run on PyQt4 as well, then stick with `app.exec_()`. So, the bottom line is: for your code to work properly on PyQt5 **and** PyQt4, use `sys.exit(app.exec_())`.

Comment: @ Boštjan Mejak.. hoora for your comment and explenation! More upvotes needed for sure! First comment so far I found that explains these minor differences that I noticed in the code. The change from pyqt4 to pyqt5 is like learning to read again (have to admit.. 10 years not programming makes one a bit rusty.. and python popping a few funballs under the hood too).

Comment: @BoštjanMejak: you do need `sys.exit()` otherwise `app.exit(1)` call doesn't lead to the corresponding exit status i.e., even on Python 3 and PyQt5, use `sys.exit(app.exec())`.

Comment: In PyQt5, they’ve fixed the order in which Qt and Python stop their process and so now we really don’t need to use sys.exit() call anymore. It’s all explained in the PyQt5 documentation.

Comment: @BoštjanMejak: *wrong*. Here's a [minimal code example](https://gist.github.com/zed/7219ddf356e25bfd9527c2762729b5d3). btw, use \@ syntax if you want me to be notified about your comments.

Answer (score 115):

That's because until Python 3, `exec` [was a reserved keyword](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), so the PyQt devs added underscore to it. From Python 3 onwards, `exec` is [no longer a reserved keyword](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) (because it is a builtin function; same situation as `print`), so it made sense in PyQt5 to provide a version without an underscore to be consistent with C++ docs, but keep a version with underscore for backwards compatibility. So for PyQt5 with Python 3, the two `exec` functions are the same. For older PyQt, only `exec_()` is available.

Comment: PyQt6 no longer supports ```exec_()```, now only ```exec()``` is available.

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of completeness, here is the current situation (as of Oct 2023):

- PyQt6: only supports `exec`
- PySide6: supports both `exec` and `exec_`
- PyQt5:  supports both `exec` and `exec_`
- PySide2:  only supports `exec_`

It should also be pointed out that this affects many other classes besides `QApplication` - for example `QMenu`, `QDialog`, `QThread`, etc.

So, moving forward, there's no longer any need to use `exec_` - unless you want to support PySide2, or the obsolete versions of Qt and Python mentioned below.

(NB: Standard Qt5 LTS support ended in May 2023, although [commercial support has been extended to May 2025](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-5.15-extended-support-for-subscription-license-holders). However, it's likely that the useful lifetime of Qt5 will continue beyond this, since [KDE is still back-porting patches](https://community.kde.org/Qt5PatchCollection) under the original Qt Open Source licence).

---

**UPDATE**:

Since PyQt4/Qt4 and Python2 are now obsolete, the following part of the answer is no longer relevant:

> On the question of whether to prefer one over the other: using `exec_`
> means you have one less thing to worry about if you ever decide to add
> support for PyQt4 and/or Python >= 2.6, and want to maintain a single
> code-base.

Comment: I think you mean Python <= 2.99, right? (Or Python2 >= 2.6.).

Comment: @FeRD. No. I mean that `exec_` will work with any version of python equal to or greater than 2.6 in combination with either pyqt4 or pyqt5. Earlier versions of python are not supported by pyqt. So `exec_` is both forwards and backwards compatible with both pyqt4 and pyqt5, and any version of python >= 2.6 (I doubt whether python-3.0.x is really viable, though).

Answer (score 2):

As of PyQt 6, `app.exec_()` is no longer supported, only `app.exec()` is.

Hence, when building new apps I only use the latter.

https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/pyqt5_differences.html?highlight=pyqt5

Comment: but what should I do instead?

Comment: I've clarified my answer. OP wanted to know whether to use `app.exec()` or `app.exec_()`. Since `app.exec_()` is no longer supported, I only use `app.exec()` in new apps. It just makes things simpler moving forward.