# PyQt5 Application exception, is this an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

Using Python3-Spyder in Anaconda on OSX 10.13.4

I have a Qt Designer App that is working fine. When I run it however I get this error in the Python Console

File ".../sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File ".../exercises/hello_world/hello_code.py", line 34, in 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

SystemExit: -1

Is this a problem?

The main code is below where hello_world is a Qt Designer ui>>py file

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from hello_world import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
#
# add text to QTextBrowser
#
        self.ui.textBrowser.setText("Hello World \n")
        self.ui.textBrowser.append("\t Hello World Again")

        self.ui.textBrowser.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyQt5 you don't need to call `sys.exit()` anymore. Just use:

```
app.exec()
```

and you are fine.

See [Should I use `app.exec()` or `app.exec_()` in my PyQt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610720/should-i-use-app-exec-or-app-exec-in-my-pyqt-application) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, you are a star!