# Why does a QDialog close the whole application if it has started a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

If I create an application with a MainWindow and a QDialog and then open and close the dialog the main window remains open.

But if my QDialog starts a thread, and once this thread is finished I close the QDialog then my whole application closes.

On the simple app below you can reproduce my problem. It's ok if I open the dialog and close without launch the tread. But if I launch the thread and close the dialog after finished the application terminate.

Can you tell me where is my mistake?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.Qt import QLabel

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        button = QPushButton("Press me for a dialog!")
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def button_clicked(self):
        my_dialog = myDialog(parent=self)
        my_dialog.exec()

class myDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('My dialog')
        self.button = QPushButton("Run long task")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.run_long_task)
        self.message = QLabel("Long task not launched")
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.message)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def run_long_task(self):
        self.message.setText('Long task running')
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = LongTask()
        self.worker.long_task_finished.connect(self.long_task_finished)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.work)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.start()

    def long_task_finished(self):
        self.message.setText('Long task finished')

class LongTask(QObject):
    long_task_finished = pyqtSignal()

    def work(self):
        sleep(5)
        self.long_task_finished.emit()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure if it'll make a difference, but it should be `my_dialog.exec_()` I believe.

Comment: Also for the record I recently had issues with threads randomly causing my window to close depending on how it was launched, in the end I went with `QRunnable` and made another class inheriting `QObject` to handle the signals. Everything I tried other than that had issues.

Comment: As I see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22614643/13749996 there is no difference with Python 3 and PyQT5. And I've tested and there is the same result with my problem.

Comment: @galio Always run your script in a console/command-window, so that you can see any tracebacks and/or qt error messages. In this case, will see that the script aborts with the message `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. Thus, the solution to your problem is to add the line `self.thread.quit()` to the `long_task_finished` slot.

Comment: @galio PS: you should also move the worker object to the thread *before* connecting any signals, otherwise you might run into [the issue discussed in the second half of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818401/984421).

Comment: first run it in console/terminal to see error messages. Without error message it is waste of time.

Comment: @ekhumoro I didn't realize that the debug mode in my IDE might not show me all the errors... So thank you for taking the time to reply!